# How to run windows batch file within shell script?

Tags: windows, shell, batch-file, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am not sure how to run `aps.bat` command within a shell script on Windows 10.

I have tried a couple of different approaches, without success I do not have more details.

Please have a look at the code below:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

output = aps.bat build $PWD;

# do some work...

echo "$output";
```

Basically, I need `aps.bat` command to be executed and to store the output to the variable.

Comment: Executing a batch script on bash? Why not just port it to a bash script?

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /e
output=$(cmd.exe /C  "aps.bat build $PWD")

# do some work...

echo $output
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am getting the same result :( 'line 3: aps: command not found'. I have pre-push file with the code written above and I am trying to setup git hook.

Comment: try output=$(cmd "/C  aps.bat build $PWD")

Comment: Still the same :( I tried 'output=$(cmd "/e/aps.bat build $PWD")' since .bat is  in the 'E' disk, I am executing script inside gitbash using this command './pre-push'. I am not sure what is wrong whit this approach?

Comment: Nothing's wrong, but gitbash might think another way. Try to cd to /e and then `start aps.bat ...`

Comment: It is not finding cmd.exe. You need to specify the full mount path to cmd.exe and most likely the full path to the batch file. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/commandline/wsl/interop

Comment: first of all calling `cmd` instead of `cmd.exe` is the problem. calling `cmd.exe` did the trick for me. and `cd /e`  before it  helped me to get rid of that annoying error 'unable to find path specified'

Comment: it is not a flag, it is disk E: in gitbash notation

Comment: Oh, then the tags are wrong because they clearly state he's using the Ubuntu subsystem that's built into Windows 10.

Answer (score 0):

Below piece of script should work, given that the bat script should be in the same path as shell script

#!/bin/bash

output = $cmd ./aps.bat build $PWD;

#do some work...

echo "$output";